# Can not run opencv_createsamples on Arch Linux

Tags: opencv, archlinux

I've installed opencv and opencv-samples on my arch linux. But when I try to run opencv_createsamples, I get an error `opencv_createsamples: command not found` I've tried to install opencv by pacman and by pip. The result is the same. Do anybody know how to fix this problem? 
Will be thankful for any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at:
https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/13231

> alalek commented on 21 Nov 2018
>
> These apps has been disabled during legacy C API removal. Rewriting them with C++ API was not an option because it is too easy to break them and hard to test.
>
> [...]
>
> Consider using these apps for training from 3.4 branch for Cascade Classifier. Model format is the same between 3.4 and 4.x.

newer opencv versions do not include the cascade training binaries anymore (because opencv tries to get rid of the old C code). Try an older opencv version. Cascade classifiers trained with older opencv version binaries should still be usable with the latest opencv lib for object detection.

Comment: I don't want use old version, Is here now have any tool to train the models?(I use opencv 4.6 and now is 2022-07-05)

Comment: Why dont you want to use the binaries of the old version? You can still use any new version for your projects, just the old executables for the training and look at it as an independent application.

Comment: In My mind, I think the old train tool may  not compatible newer opencv.

Comment: With the train tool you create an xml file which is compatible to new opencv. Just make sure you use traincacade instead of haar-training (which is outdated in old and new).